# Where is the MacBook Air (13") Mid 2012 fan exhaust?

Tags: macbook-pro

I would like to put a plastic dust cover on my MacBook Air, but I'm not sure whether it would obstruct the fan exhaust.

Below is a drawing that shows the soft cover.

[image]

I know someone that would make it for me from the material in those plastic bags with zipper, like the one below.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

It should be directly in the back, toward the bottom (across almost the entire machine). Look for the black plastic strip across the back.